# Using frames around subreports

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]
I am generating the reports using ireport-4.5.0,jasper-reports 4.5.0,spring mvc.I have 6 sub reports in my main report and in main report i have placed each subreport in seperate detail band surrounded with frame for having borders around the reports.If any of my detail band exceeds page 1 and displays in page2 then the frame in page1 loses the bottom border and the frame in page 2 loses the top border.It is looking very ugly.How can i set my frame to have all the four borders

Please find the below attachment.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of resulted report and the design of your report?

Comment: Hi Alex Thanks For giving the reply.I have edited my original quesion by attaching the image.

Comment: Which borders are missing (can you point at image)?

Comment: Hi Alex,actually i am not able to piont in the image.If you look at the image it is of 2 pages,in the first page the bottom border is missing and in the second page the top border is missing.Here i am placing the subreport in frame for border purpose.When the subreport has more data then the frame is splitting and it is missing the bottom border and top border if it exceeds a page.

Comment: I'm looking at your image and I can see borders (at bottom and on top). Can you mark missing border at the image? Can you additionally add the screenshot of your report's design (screenshot from the GUI report's templates designer)  or post the *jrxml* file?

Comment: Try to add a frame in column footer with bottom border, may be it will help you.

Comment: Hi Alex,I have marked the missing borders in my original image.Can you plz look into it.